# PMD "Found 'DD'-anomaly" vs "only one return statement"

Tags: java, pmd

I try to remove all PMD warnings in my project and have some difficulties. I have a method that returns a Container object. This was my original method (simplified):

```
try {
    return setResult();
} catch (Exception ex) {

}
return null;
```

PMD warned that there are 2 return statements. So I tried this:

```
Container result = null;
try {
    result = setResult();
} catch (Exception ex) {

}
return result;
```

=> PMD warned about initializing with null. So I tried this:

```
Container result;
try {
    result = setResult();
} catch (Exception ex) {

}
return result;
```

=> Eclipse did not compile this, suggesting to use the "= null" variation.

What am I missing here? How do I have to write this method without PMD warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the second approach you show:

```
Container result = null;
try {
    result = setResult();
} catch (Exception ex) {

}
return result;
```

Because, as PMD points out, it is important to avoid unnecessary return statements for the purpose of reducing complexity.

The PMD documentation classifies the [NullAssignment rule as "controversial"](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.5/rules/java/controversial.html). It's usefulness very much depends on the context. Here is the sample code they provide:

```
public void bar() {
  Object x = null; // this is OK
  x = new Object();
   // big, complex piece of code here
  x = null; // this is not required
   // big, complex piece of code here
}
```

So, unless you can assign the `Container` variable with a meaningful value beforehand - you should probably ignore this rule for this code fragment.

If you want to completely avoid the null assignment, you could use [Guava's Optional](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html). In this case it has the following advantages:

1. It forces you to think about the absence of a value
2. It makes the code more understandable
3. It makes PMD happy